# Python - generalised function to subset columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am currently trying to create a generalised function which subsets a dataset based on the list of column names specified in the argument parameters.
This function works well when **one** column is specified, but fails when more than one column is specified.
I would like a function which is able to accommodate multiple columns input as the argument parameter.

```
import pandas as pd
testdb=pd.DataFrame({'first':[1,3,4],'second':[1,3,4],'last':[1,3,4],'static':[1,3,4]})

def subsetting(df,cols):
    print(df.loc[:, [cols, "static"]])
  
# this works
subsetting(testdb,'first')

# this does not work
subsetting(testdb,str('first','second'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would design the API like this.

You can passed in a list of `cols` that you want to select from dataframe and then use

```
df.loc[:, [*cols, "static"]]
```

syntax to unpack it as separate column names. ie,

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> 
>>> testdb = pd.DataFrame(
...     {"first": [1, 3, 4], "second": [1, 3, 4], "last": [1, 3, 4], "static": [1, 3, 4]}
... )
>>> 
>>> 
>>> def subsetting(df, cols):
...     print(df.loc[:, [*cols, "static"]])
... 
>>> 
>>> subsetting(testdb, cols=("first", "second"))
   first  second  static
0      1       1       1
1      3       3       3
2      4       4       4
```

Comment: The function works beautifully for 2 or more columns, but if i include a single column (even as a list), it does not work. How do i account for that?

Comment: `subsetting(testdb, cols=["first"])` or `subsetting(testdb, cols=(["first"]))` will work. `subsetting(testdb, cols=("first"))` will result in an error because `*cols` will attempt to iterate through the string and use the individual characters as column names.